# Native support for Apple Silicon

Tags: macvim, macos

Is there a timeline for when the Mac-version of Vim will get native support for Apple's new system architecture, Apple Silicon?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se], Marina!

Answer (score 1):

The macvim team provides "universal app" builds giving native support for the Apple Silicon architecture since [March 2021](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases/tag/snapshot-170).

Latest releases are available via https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases